# Dropping ‘any’ in ‘any one’

Tags: word-usage

This question is about the usage of *one of the ___.*

An example is in the following excerpt:
*Two brothers leave a club. The club manager decides that one of the remaining midfielders can play as either a midfielder or as a defender.*

In this case, would *one of the remaining midfielders* refer to a specific, particular individual, or would it refer to *any* individual? Or would it perhaps, be too vague to ascertain?

Answer (score 1):

Logically, 'anyone' or 'one' limit this to the same counting situation.

But words aren't simply their logical denotations.

'Anyone' hints that a decision on exactly who the individual has not yet been made, or that it doesn't matter who it may be. 'One' could mean that or may imply, as you note, that a particular individual has already been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, *one of the remaining midfielders* refers to "the midfielders left in that specific team".

How *many* midfielders there are left depends on the kind of sport we're talking about.

So: *one of the remaining midfielders* literally refers only to the remaining midfielders of that team.